# Twilio API to access WhatsApp Templates?

Tags: whatsapp, twilio-api

I am writing a Hubspot application which will use Twilio to send WhatsApp messages from workflows.

Because we are initiating the conversation we must use a template.

I would like to provide the user in Hubspot a choice of templates to use. To do that, I need to retrieve the approved templates from our Twilio account.

I cannot find any APIs which allow me to retrieve our WhatsApp message templates from Twilio. I've searched all of the Twilio documentation.

Does anyone know of any possible workaround, or whether I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 1):

We didn't have this API when you asked (3 months ago) -- but you were clearly not the only one asking!  So, we've listened, and are rolling out a new API for this, and other template use/creation across our platform!

https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1

Best,
-David